# Ternary default on boxed boolean with unset key for NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

So I've tested this, but just wanting to make sure it wasn't some random undefined behavior. I want to use the shorthand ternary on a dictionary but I want it to return a default value when it is not set. Here is the test I wrote:

```
NSMutableDictionary *test = [NSMutableDictionary new];
test[@"test_1"] = @NO;
test[@"test_2"] = @YES;

BOOL test1 = [test[@"test_1"] boolValue] ?: NO;
BOOL test2 = [test[@"test_2"] boolValue] ?: NO;
BOOL test3 = [test[@"test_3"] boolValue] ?: NO;

LogDebug(@"test1 = %@", (test1 ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
LogDebug(@"test2 = %@", (test2 ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
LogDebug(@"test3 = %@", (test3 ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

Now I got the correct value for test3, but I'm wondering whether thats just a random fluke of undefined behavior. I'm wondering this because when I checked for that value in the debugger by typing this in the console:

```
po [test[@"test_3"] boolValue]
```

I got:

```
error: no known method '-boolValue'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Are the results of test3 reliable?

Comment: i think boolValue method is for NSString type and you are using it to check for an object.test[@"test_3"] doesn't return a string,hence boolValue will not work in this case. Also you didn't mention about test[@"test_3"] in the code. What does  test[@"test_3"] contain?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri You are incorrect. `@NO`, and `@YES` are `NSNumber` instances. `NSNumber` has a `boolValue` method. This question has nothing to do with `NSString`.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to test:  the existence of the value for a particular key in the dictionary, whether the value for a particular key is actually a BOOL value type if it exists, or whether the (assumed exists and type BOOL) value for a particular key is YES or NO.  Whichever of these three you're trying to accomplish will yield different test criteria.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels The goal is posted clearly in the opening paragraph. Get the `BOOL` value if it exists, otherwise get a default value (`NO` in this case).

Comment: I meant to say boolValue work for NSString but not for other object types.I forgot that it works for a NSnumber .@rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`NSDictionary` (and its subclass, `NSMutableDictionary`) is documented as returning `nil` for a key with no value.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKeyedSubscript:)

In Objective-C, [sending a message to `nil` is documented to return `NO` when you expect a `BOOL` result](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW22).

Therefore, **if you want the default value to be `NO`**, this suffices:

```
BOOL test3 = [test[@"test_3"] boolValue];
```

If you only intend to store `NSString` keys and `NSNumber` values (which `@YES` and `@NO` are) in the dictionary, you can declare it like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *test = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

And then you can use a property accessor if you prefer:

```
BOOL test3 = test[@"test_3"].boolValue;
```

**If you want a different default value** (and the only other possibility for `BOOL` values is `YES`), then @trojanfoe's suggestion of creating a method is what I'd recommend, but I'd probably make a more general category on `NSDictionary` like this:

```
// NSDictionary+kailoon.h

@interface NSDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType> (kailoon)

- (ObjectType)kailoon_objectForKey:(KeyType)key default:(ObjectType)defaultObject;

@end
```

```
// NSDictionary+kailoon.m

@implementation NSDictionary (kailoon)

- (id)kailoon_objectForKey:(id)key default:(id)defaultObject {
    id value = self[key];
    return value ? value : defaultObject;
}

@end
```

Then I'd use it like this:

```
BOOL test3 = [test kailoon_objectForKey:@"test_3" default:@YES].boolValue;
```

**As for your debugger problem,** it's incorrect to use `po` to print a `BOOL`, because `po` means “print object” and a `BOOL` is not an object. (It is a primitive.) So you should just use `p`. But that's not really the problem here. To fix the “no known method” problem, you use a cast, like this:

```
(lldb) p (BOOL)[test[@"test_3"] boolValue]
(BOOL) $1 = NO
```

Answer (score 0):

That code is reliable, but only for booleans and only when the default value is `NO`, as non-existence of the value in the dictionary will give `NO` and hence the default value will be used.

However it's somewhat clumsy as:

```
 [test[@"test_3"] boolValue] ?: NO;
```

is basing the result of the ternary expression on whether the boolean stored in the `NSNumber` is `YES` or `NO`, when what you want to know is *is the value set in the dictionary?*.

This is better:

```
BOOL test1 = test[@"test_1"] != nil ? [test[@"test_1"] boolValue] : NO;
```

and will use the default value only if the dictionary does not contain the specified key.  This pattern can also be extended to other types and can also be used if the default value is `YES`.

Wrapped into a method (recommended), it would be the following (this code also checks the value *type*):

```
- (BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)key defaultValue:(BOOL)defaultValue
{
    id value = self.dictionary[key];
    return [value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] ? [value boolValue] : defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: The question states that the goal is to get a default value of `NO` if there is no `BOOL` value for a given key.

Comment: That doesn't mean the OP (or someone else) won't decide later to put other types into the dictionary.  They might also decide to use `YES` as the default value at some point..

Comment: Of course but then this whole question and its answers won't apply.

Comment: Actually in that case (wanting `YES` as the default) this answer *will* apply.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting from your code is correct and defined.

First off, your code can be simplified to:

```
BOOL test1 = [test[@"test_1"] boolValue];
BOOL test2 = [test[@"test_2"] boolValue];
BOOL test3 = [test[@"test_3"] boolValue];
```

You will get `NO` for any key that doesn't exist. If `test[@"some_nonexistent_key"]` returns `nil`, calling `boolValue` on `nil` results in `NO`.

The debugger is just getting confused because it doesn't know what to do with the call to `boolValue` on `nil` since there are more than one possible `boolValue` methods (`NSNumber` and `NSString`).

Comment: I am backing-out of that comment.  It will work, as you say, however I am concerned that it only works for booleans in the dictionary (given non-existence of the value will give `NO`).  If that pattern was extended to other types, there would be issues.

Comment: @trojanfoe The question is about a dictionary full of `BOOL` values wrapped in `NSNumber`. The code also works if they dictionary happens to have `NSString` objects too. Obviously this isn't meant to handle any data type but that's not the question.

Comment: Yeah, understood, but you know how code like this gets extended without thinking.  It won't work for any other type stored in `NSNumber`.  As mentioned in my answer, the code is a bit clumsy.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sure it will. `[@3.14 boolValue]` gives `YES`. `[@0 boolValue]` gives `NO`. Any zero value gives `NO`. Any non-zero values gives `YES`.

Comment: No I mean if they want to get a `float` out and provide a default `float` value.  The code, as it stands, won't work for a default value of `YES` either.

Comment: @trojanfoe If the requirement changes, my answer would change to match. My answer focuses on the question being asked.